# Find the area of region

Tags: calculus

Find the area of the region bounded by the curves $y=2x^2-6x+5$ and $y=x^2+6x-15$.

I found the critical points $2$ and $10$. My trouble is making the integral work. My teacher's answer key says that the area is $85.33$ but I keep getting something different.

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, the quadratic polynomials intersect at $x=2,10$.

On $[2,10]$, we have $x^2+6x-15\geq 2x^2-6x+5$ since
$$
(x^2+6x-15)-(2x^2-6x+5)=-x^2+12x-20=-(x-2)(x-10)
$$ 
is positive between the roots.
So the area is
$$
\int_2^{10}((x^2+6x-15)-(2x^2-6x+5))dx=\int_2^{10}(-x^2+12x-20)dx
$$
$$
=-\frac{x^3}{3}+6x^2-20x \Big|_2^{10}=-\frac{1000}{3}+600-200+\frac{8}{3}-24+40
$$
$$
=-\frac{992}{3}+416=\frac{256}{3}=85.3333\ldots
$$

Comment: How can you tell that the second y= is greater than/equal to the first y=?

Comment: @MiltonFriedman Is it better like that?

Comment: Sorry could you explain a little more simply on how the second y= is greater/equal to the first? I'ma beginner in calculus.

Comment: @MiltonFriedman Do you understand how I factored the difference between the two polynomials?

Comment: Oh yes I see that. But how does that determine which is greater or lesser?

Comment: @MiltonFriedman [Click here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/thmtkb4eg1), to see what the graph of $-x^2+12x-20$ looks like.

Comment: @MiltonFriedman So is we prove that $p_1(x)-p_2(x)\geq 0$ on $[2,10]$, it means that $p_1(x)$ is greater than $p_2(x)$ (or equal) on this interval. Since we have factored $p_1-p_2$, we can easily study its sign. It is negative outside the roots, positive between them. Ok?

Comment: An alternative approach is to note that $-x^2+12x-20$ canot change sign except (possibly) at $2$ and $10$. so find the sign at "test points," one in $(-\infty,2)$, one in $(2,10)$, one in $(10,\infty)$. But it is obvious the thing is negative for $x$ big positive or negative. so need only test say $x=4$. Positive!

Comment: @AndréNicolas I did not specify any approach, though. Thanks for helping helping. Just: as we know the sign alternates, and it is clear from the coefficient of $x^2$ that its negative at large, it must be positive between the roots and there is no need to test anything for that.

Comment: But how'd you know to subtract the first y= from the second y=? Why couldn't you subtract both the y= the other way?

Comment: @MiltonFriedman If you subtract in the other direction, then you will find that the difference $P-2-p_1$ is now negative between the roots. And the conclusion will be the same: $p_2-p_1<0$ implies $p_2<p_1$ on $(2,10)$.